# Problem installing reader software for Estonian ID card for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, sudo, card-reader

I updated my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and now I have problems to install Estonian ID card reader software.

When I trie to use the installation script, that I have downloaded from https://installer.id.ee/?lang=eng, using command "sudo sh install-esteid-ubuntu.sh" and terminal gives me following notice. "You run this script as root. DO NOT RUN RANDOM SCRIPTS AS ROOT".

How can I install this software?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you, literally, tried to execute the `install-esteid-ubuntu.sh` script as root user. Obviously so, because you prepended `sudo` to the command:

```
sudo sh install-esteid-ubuntu.sh
```

Instead try the following command, as mentioned in the [official installation instructions](http://www.id.ee/index.php?id=34448):

```
sh install-esteid-ubuntu.sh
```

This should then successfully start the script, and the script will ask you for the superuser password when it wants to run individual commands as a superuser. It will need that, but will buckle if you want to pre-emptively run the whole thing as superuser …